# How to add prefix and subfix in OpenOffice Cell - and merging into new cell?

Tags: openoffice.org, openoffice-calc

How can I add prefix and postfix in a cell? I need to insert 30000 Data Set.
Is there any automation?

`Cell A` , `Cell B` , `CellC`
`word` , `word-type` , `meanings`
`Love` , `n` , `to like or enjoy something very much`

INTO

`Love (n) to like or enjoy something very much`

many thanks in advance.

best regards,
ko

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ko,

I assume that you have tried things like in e.g. cell `D1`:

```
=A1&" ("&B1&") "&C1
```

Comment: Hi Robert, Thanks a lots. I used it like =" ("&B1&") "&C1